# Limit AWS Lambda to max 3 retries from SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge

The setup below runs every 5 minutes to put a message into a SQS queue and the lambda pools message from it. If the lambda returns an error it retries every 30 seconds until it succeeds. The aim is to limit retries to maximum 3 attempts so the message goes to DLQ. However, I cannot find the correct configuration to achieve this.

I added `--attributes '{"RedrivePolicy":"{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:000000000000:api-dead-letter-queue\",\"maxReceiveCount\":\"3\"}"}'` to `api-queue` but nothing changed.

I introduced piece below but it didn't change anything too.

```sh
aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 lambda put-function-event-invoke-config \
    --function-name api-lambda \
    --maximum-event-age-in-seconds 3600 \
    --maximum-retry-attempts 3
```

What exactly am I missing below to achieve max 3 tries please?

```sh
aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 lambda create-function \
    --function-name api-lambda \
    --handler lambda/main \
    --runtime go1.x \
    --role api-role \
    --zip-file fileb://lambda.zip

aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue \
    --queue-name api-dead-letter-queue
    
aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue \
    --queue-name api-queue

aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 events put-rule \
    --name api-rule \
    --schedule-expression 'rate(5 minutes)'

aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 events put-targets \
    --rule api-rule \
    --targets '[{"Id":"1","Arn":"arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:000000000000:api-queue","Input":"{\"key\":\"val\"}"}]'

aws --profile localstack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566 lambda create-event-source-mapping \
    --function-name api-lambda \
    --event-source-arn arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:000000000000:api-queue
```

Comment: Are you confident that `localstack` supports that? Did you check on the actual AWS resources?

Comment: Localstack lets you use `RedrivePolicy` to move messages to DLQ after certain amount of retrieve attempts so I am sure it des support. "Did you check on the actual AWS resources?" - If you mean the AWS Console, I don't have an AWS account to verify it.

Comment: Does your lambda get invoked? Or nothing works?

Comment: Everything works but I want max three retires, not indefinite which is the issue here. After the third attempt, the message should be moved to DLQ.

Comment: `put-function-event-invoke-config` is for async invocations. It is not related at all to SQS lambda even source mapping. Don't know about localstock, but on real AWS, you have to setup bunch of permissions to make this work. In localstack, no permissions are required for anything?

Comment: Yes no permission required for Localstack.